# getting lat long from google map in react native

Tags: google-maps, react-native, autocomplete

> **I am unable to get the lat long from the google map API, Using React  Native**.
>
> **I am using this Extension for auto complete** [react-native-google-places-autocomplete](https://github.com/FaridSafi/react-native-google-places-autocomplete)

I am Building a rideshare application, For this, i have to get the pick-up and drop location of the user. With many efforts,i get the Auto-Complete  Work.

> Now the problem is, i need the latitude and longitude of the selected Locations. i tried but i can`t.

Need Help, Thank you.

```
<GooglePlacesAutocomplete
  placeholder='Enter Location'
  minLength={2}
  autoFocus={false}
  returnKeyType={'default'}
  fetchDetails={true}
  onPress={(data, details = null) => { 
// I tried this One 
// Tried to get the reponce from API HERE

  console.log(data, details);
}}
  styles={{
    textInputContainer: {
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)',
      borderTopWidth: 0,
      borderBottomWidth:0
    },
    textInput: {
      marginLeft: 0,
      marginRight: 0,
      height: 38,
      color: '#5d5d5d',
      fontSize: 16
    },
    predefinedPlacesDescription: {
      color: '#1faadb'
    },
  }}
  query={{
    // available options: https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/autocomplete
    key: 'YOUR API KEY',
    language: 'en', // language of the results
    types: '(cities)' // default: 'geocode'
  }}
  currentLocation={false}
/>
```

Comment: Well, what have you tried so far?

Comment: Please check recheck the question i put the code 
See the onPress Event

Comment: i am getting nothing in the data and details variable

Comment: I never working with `react-native` but you must understand that google have a lot of api. So autocomplete only bring you certain info about wanted place but not lat-long coordinates. For that you must use `geocoder API` : https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro

Comment: I dont know exactly how your library should work, but I am using https://github.com/tolu360/react-native-google-places for autocomplete, and it's working perfectly. If you need I can help you with this library, with a functional example.

Comment: Let me try your suggestions, Hope it work

Comment: Don't forget to enable the `google API places` from your google account.

Comment: @oma i already enabled the API, And its returning results correctly, but the problem is i can get the lat long.

Comment: added an example with the suggested library.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import RNGooglePlaces from 'react-native-google-places';

//constructor here

openSearchModal() {
  RNGooglePlaces.openAutocompleteModal()
  .then((place) => {
  // place represents user's selection from the
  // suggestions and it is a simplified Google Place object.
  console.log(place);  //here you will have lat and long
     this.setState({
       address: place,
     })
  })
  .catch(error => console.log("ERROR: " + error.message));  // error is a Javascript Error object
}

render() {
   <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.openSearchModal()}>
       <Text>Map</Text>
   </TouchableOpacity>
}
```

Comment: How it's going ?

Comment: Hey there i am getting error react-native-google-places when i try to install this,

**Android dependency 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps' has different version for the compile (11.6.2) and runtime (16.0.0) classpath. You should manually set the same version via DependencyResolution**